# How to Get Header Values

Tags: .net, wcf, http, wcf-web-api, asp.net-web-api

How can I access header values from a web method in WCF Web API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

(using System.Web;)

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["myValue"]);
```